# Change forms at the start rather than after change

Tags: php, jquery, forms, echo

I have an update function with a radio button and forms. The user clicks the update button to update their contact details. I have a JQuery function in place to change the forms depending on which radio button option the user chooses. I'll show the photos first then explain. 
[image]

[image]

Its only when the user selects another radio button, the goes back to the company button, that the JQuery function shows the correct forms. How do I make it can show the right forms right off the bat?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Edit contacts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  listenForInputChanges();
})

function listenForInputChanges() {
$('#contactType >input').change(function(){
 console.log('val is '+$(this).val())
switch($(this).val()) {
case 'Individual':
$('#nameDiv').show();
$('#companyDiv').show();
$('#titleDiv').show();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
break;

case 'Team':
$('#nameDiv').show();
$('#companyDiv').show();
$('#titleDiv').hide();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
break;

case 'Company':
$('#nameDiv').show();
$('#companyDiv').hide();
$('#titleDiv').hide();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
break;
}
})
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <h2>Edit Contact</h2>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Changes to contact type?
</label>
<div id="contactType" class="col-sm-10">
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" <?=$r['Contact_type']=="Individual" ? "Checked" : ""?> value="Individual">Individual
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" <?=$r['Contact_type']=="Team" ? "Checked" : ""?> value="Team">Team
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" <?=$r['Contact_type']=="Company" ? "Checked" : ""?> value="Company">Company

</div>
</div>


<div id="nameDiv" class="form-group">
<label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" id="input1" value="<?php echo $r['Name']; ?>" placeholder="Name" />
</div>
</div>     

<div id="companyDiv" class="form-group">
<label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="comp"  class="form-control" id="input1" value="<?php echo $r['Company'] ?>" placeholder="Company" />
</div>
</div> 

<div id="titleDiv" class="form-group">
<label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="title"  class="form-control" id="input1" value="<?php echo $r['Title'] ?>" placeholder="Title" />
</div>
</div>  



<div id="phoneDiv" class="form-group">
<label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="int" name="urstel"  class="form-control" id="input1"  value="
<?php echo $r['Phone'] ?>" placeholder="Phone" />
</div>
</div>   


<div id="emailDiv" class="form-group">
<label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" id="input1"  value="
<?php echo $r['Email'] ?>" placeholder="E-mail" />
</div>
</div>  

<div id="addressDiv" class="form-group">
<label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="location"  class="form-control" id="input1"  value="<?php echo $r['Address'] ?>" placeholder="Address" />
</div>
</div>  


  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="Update" />
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean off the bat ?

Comment: Ah my bad. I mean  that when the update page is opened. I want the correct forms to be shown, rather than the case of the photos above where you need to click the radio button again, and the correct forms will show thereafter.

Comment: But when `onload` it selects the right radio automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 listenForInputChanges($('#contactType > input').val());
});
$('#contactType >input').change(function(){
 listenForInputChanges($(this).val());
});

function listenForInputChanges(inp)
{
switch(inp) {
case 'Individual':
$('#nameDiv').show();
$('#companyDiv').show();
$('#titleDiv').show();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
break;

case 'Team':
$('#nameDiv').show();
$('#companyDiv').show();
$('#titleDiv').hide();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
break;

case 'Company':
$('#nameDiv').show();
$('#companyDiv').hide();
$('#titleDiv').hide();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
break;
}
}
```

**EDIT**
Also replace your shorthand declaration on radio button like this

```
    <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" <?php 
($r['Contact_type']=="Individual") ? " checked " : ""?> 
 value="Individual">Individual

 <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" <?php ($r['Contact_type']=="Team") ? 
 " checked" : ""?> value="Team">Team

 <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" <?php 
 ($r['Contact_type']=="Company") ? " checked " : ""?> value="Company">Company
```

Comment: Thanks jerome! Unfortunately the above does not work. :(

Comment: @kerrysun i've done some changes might give it a try again.